# Why doesn't SymPy replace exponentials?

Tags: sympy

Simple example:

```
from sympy import *
n = symbols('n',integer=True)
x,y = symbols('x,y')
expression = exp(I*n*x)
expression.subs(exp(I*n),y)
#>> exp(I*n*x)
```

Why doesn't SymPy replace the `exp(I*x)` to give `y**n`? It works perfectly fine the other way around (replacing `y` in `y**n` with `exp(I*x)` to give `exp(I*n*x)`). Is there a hack to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

`subs` might not work in general if the expression you are replacing doesn't appear exactly in the expression.

One workaround is to use `replace` with pattern matching to replace a more general pattern

```
>>> a = Wild('a')
>>> expression.replace(exp(I*n*a), y**a)
y**x
```